# How to scroll a tableViewController's view with only static cells inside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a tableViewController which stores a form for the user to input their information. This form is grouped by a couple of static cells instead of dynamic cells. So it doesn't access the delegate method       `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Also, I have controlled that user can add some of the attachment and keep stacking. These attachments are stored in a single UIView each. The problem is, when more than 6 attachments were added, the attachment view starts to go out of the screen height. How can I make this tableViewController scrollable?

Please tell me if you need me to show any code.

Comment: It can scroll as default when cells is out of frame.Did you turn it off?

Comment: I just got one cell and keep appending UIVIew below instead of cells. And no, I have set this: `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set it scrollable.And you should add these views to table footer view and increase its height at the same time.By this,table view will be able to scroll once its height is bigger than that of frame.

Comment: Can I manually set the tableView's height? I've tried this:
`[self.tableView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight + 100)` but it still doesn't work. 
P.S. the screenWidth and screenHeight I get those by this code:
`CGFloat screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
CGFloat screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);`

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk No, you can't.It's top level view in table view controller.